# How to analytically derive the geometric properties of a hyperbola and programatically use them to graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, hyperbolic-geometry

I have the following equation:

$$
\left(10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1}+x\right)
\left(10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1}+y\right)
= k
$$

[Entering the above in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28k%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29%2Bx%29%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28k%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29+%2B+y%29+%3D+k) gives some details.

I'm looking to graph that for a given $k$, e.g.
[for $k=416375599$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28416375599%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29%2Bx%29%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28416375599%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29+%2B+y%29+%3D+416375599)
or
[for $k=115701923737787$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28115701923737787%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29%2Bx%29%2810%5E%28floor%28ln%28sqrt%28115701923737787%29%29%2Fln%2810%29%29-1%29+%2B+y%29+%3D+115701923737787).

I'm actually only interested in $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R^+$.

Regardless if you expand the properties tab on the graph you get analytic calculations for the following properties: foci, vertices, center, semimajor axis length, semiminor axis length, focal parameter, eccentricity and asymptotes.

I'm assuming derivations of these 8 properties are sufficient to graph a given $k$, I'm just not sure

1. how to derive those properties and
2. how to use them to programmatically draw the curve.

It is important for my application that I do not resort to brute force plotting.

*Update:*

I have looked at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html and cracked my pre-calc book (which was from a course I took 15 years ago and is in a chapter we didn't actually make it to). In both cases I do not see a way to calculate the foci analytically from my equation for a given k.

After that is explained I think I need to perform algebraic manipulation to get it into a standard form to use the methodology described in that article. I'm fairly confident I'd be able to figure that out using wolfram (I certainly have no chance doing it by hand).

I would also appreciate links to algorithms in a general purpose language (C-syntax appreciated) to apply that methodology, as I really don't need to actually graph it, I just need the computational equivalent of a graph (don't ask).

I've determined the properties to be as followed:

foci: $(-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} -\sqrt{2*k},-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} -\sqrt{2*k}),(-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} +\sqrt{2*k},-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} +\sqrt{2*k})$

vertices: $(-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} -\sqrt{k},-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} -\sqrt{k}),(-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} +\sqrt{k},-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} +\sqrt{k})$

center: $(-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1},-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1})$

semimajor axis length: $\sqrt{2*k}$

semiminor axis length: $\sqrt{2*k}$

focal parameter: $\sqrt{k}$

eccentricity: $\sqrt2$

asymptotes: $x=-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1} | y=-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1}$

I wish I could say I gained insight from those calculations, but I just looked at what wolfram churned out for the values and figured out the formula.

Now on to part 2: How do I use this information to write an algorithm to graph without resorting to brute force? Basically I am trying to gain insight on the curve, so I can limit the potential range of integer y solutions for a range of x solutions, and be able to pick the size of my x range test to optimize against the curvature, so I have to test against few values as possible.

Comment: This [MathWorld.Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html) link should contain more than what you need to know.

Comment: I should add that, given the information in the link I have given, you would still need to rotate the graph 45 degrees counterclockwise.  The resulting plot is then called a **rectangular** (or **equilateral**) hyperbola.

Comment: @ArnieDris : can we chat in the stackoverflow room? I have a lot of stupid questions and I don't want to pollute the comments section. It's been over 15 years since pre-calc and I'm pretty sure we never covered this. I don't think this would have been covered in calculus or differential equations, and as an engineer that's as far as my formal math education goes.

Comment: I just cracked my pre-calc book. There is about 5 pages on graphic hyperbola's, however all of the examples assume you already know the foci. In this case I need to derive the foci from my equation. So for a given k I need to transform the equation I have provided into a standard hyperbola formula in order to use the link @ArnieDris provides. I have absolutely no idea how to do that...

Comment: You should use LaTeX in your posts. Just placing a link is very unreadable

Comment: @becko: I have no idea how to use LaTeX, been meaning to learn. I would appreciate it if someone who knew what they were doing with that language could make this post more presentable.

Comment: @MvG: thank you so much for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

$xy=1$ is you standard $y=1/x$ hyperbola, with center at the origin and the coordinate axes as asymptotes. $xy=k$ takes that and scales it by $\sqrt k$ in both coordinate directions. Finally $(x-x_c)(y-y_c)=k$ takes that and moves its ceter to $(x_c,y_c)$. You just have $x_c$ and $y_c$ which happen to be complicated formulas in $k$, namely

$$
x_c=y_c=-10^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\sqrt k}{\ln10}\right\rfloor-1}
$$

So the hyperbola is *still* axis-aligned.
Therefore it is very similar to the standard hyperbola I started with.
As Wolfram Alpha will tell you, the standard hyperbola has these properties:

> - foci: $(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2), (\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$
> - vertices: $(-1,-1), (1,1)$
> - center: $(0, 0)$
> - semimajor axis length: $\sqrt2$
> - semiminor axis length: $\sqrt2$
> - focal parameter: $1$
> - eccentricity: $\sqrt2$
> - asymptotes: $x = 0, y = 0$

The points (i.e. foci, vertices, center) you have to scale by $\sqrt k$ then translate by $(x_c,y_c)$. The lengths (axis lengths, focal parameter) you just scale by $\sqrt k$. The eccentricity is a dimensionless constant affected by neither scaling nor translation, so it remains fixed at $\sqrt2$. The asymptotes get translated to $x=x_c$ and $y=y_c$.

Comment: This was kind of helpful, although I actually had figured out the calculations for this information through induction before you posted. The question I have now is how to use this to gain insights into the graph